# How can I find all involutions whose reciprocals are also involutions?

Tags: functional-equations, involutions

How can I solve the following functional equation?

$$\frac{1}{f(x)} = f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$$

This functional equation amounts to finding all involutions whose reciprocals are also involutions.

I've found two solutions, $y=\pm\frac{1}{x}.$

Comment: Hint: Involutions are invertible functions. What properties do invertible functions have?

Comment: They have inverses

Comment: But they're also injective and surjective. Compare and contrast with your conclusions so far.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Their work so far is mostly wrong though.

Comment: You have $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I think this can be simplified to finding all functions $f$ such that $\frac{1}{f(x)} = f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{f(x)}=f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

$f(x)f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=1$

In fact this functional equation belongs to the form of http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe2111.pdf.

$\therefore f(x)=\pm e^{C\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\right)}$ , where $C(u,v)$ is any antisymmetric function.